# Array de JSON com checkbox AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, array, checkbox, angularjs-directives

Estou tentando formar um JSON com o que está selecionado pelo `checkbox`, porém quando seleciono ele insere, mas quando tento tirar o *check*, ele insere novamente. O correto seria funcionar [dessa maneira](http://www.programming-free.com/2014/05/angularjs-retrieve-multiple-checkbox-selected-options.html), mas formando um array de JSON e não só palavras ou números.

```js
var crud = angular.module('crud',[]);


crud.controller('CadUserController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
 
$scope.dbProfiles = [{"id":1,"nome":"Adminstrador"},{"id":2,"nome":"Tabeliao"},{"id":3,"nome":"Substituto"},{"id":4,"nome":"Escrevente"},{"id":5,"nome":"Caixa"},{"id":6,"nome":"Auxiliar"}];

   // selected fruits
   $scope.selection = [];
   var profiles= [];

   // toggle selection for a given fruit by name
   $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(profileId) {
     var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf({"idProfile":profileId});
     // is currently selected
     if (idx > -1) {
       $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
     }
     // is newly selected
     else {
       $scope.selection.push({"idProfile":profileId});
     }
   };
 }]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="crud"> 
<div ng-controller="CadUserController" class="col-md-9 form-group">
   <label for="perfil">Perfil</label><br>            

   <span ng-repeat="profile in dbProfiles">
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{profile.id}}" 
            ng-checked="selection.indexOf(profile.id) > -1" 
            ng-click="toggleSelection(profile.id)"> {{profile.nome}}

   </span>
   {{selection|json}}
</div>
  </div>
<script src="resources/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Você não conseguiu implementar o exemplo que você mesmo postou?

Comment: Você precisa de um json ou você precisa apenas saber o que foi checkado?

Comment: eu consegui implementar, porém eu preciso de algo mais completo, inves de [1,2,4] eu preciso de [{"profile":1},{"profile":2},{"profile":3}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, mas pelo que vi em um comentário você queria algo mais "completo" e não só pegar o `[1,2,3]`.

Veja se esse exemplo que montei pode te ajudar: http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/21023/

---

**Atualizado**

Acho que consegui entender um pouco melhor o problema, caso o exemplo de cima não resolva, tente esse: http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/21024/

Na função que é chamada no `ng-click` passa uma String junto com o código do profile: `ng-click="toggleSelection('profile: '+profile.id)"`

Dessa forma o resultado ficará assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]